# Tokens not creating from a variable by for [batch]

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i want to extract tokens from a variable by using / as delimiter.
i used this ::

```
set fileinput=properties\iam\self_iam_properties.xml
for  /f "tokens=*delims=\" %%a in (%fileinput%) do @echo %%a
```

which gives me following error :

```
The system cannot find the file properties\iam\self_iam_properties.xml.
```

why is it searching for a file, i just need to use the value present in the variable. i do not want to take values from a file.

Also after parsing, i wish to create a file named `self_iam_parsedoutput.txt` so for that i need to extract `self_iam_` from the input file name. how to proceed with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `%fileinput%` in double quotes to treat it like a string.

```
for /f "tokens=*delims=\" %%a in ("%fileinput%") do @echo %%a
```

Note that because you're using `tokens=*`, it won't actually split into multiple variables.  If you want each section of the path to get its own variable, you could use something like `tokens=1-26`

A second way to escape variables in `for /f` is to run a command which outputs the variable.

```
for /f %a in ('echo.%variable%')
```

This form is useful if you're otherwise running into problems with double quotes.

As for the filename change, if the input file is always `xyz_properties.xml` and the output is always `xyz_parsedoutput.txt`, then you can use a simple text substitution of the form `%variable:old=new%`

```
set inputfile=self_iam_properties.xml
set outputfile=%inputfile:properties.xml=parsedoutput.txt%
```

Comment: Also after parsing, i wish to create a file named self_iam_parsedoutput.txt so for that i need to extract self_iam_ from the input file name. how to proceed with that ?

Comment: Updated to include bit about text substitution in variables.